# logic gates, implementation

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

Task: Draw an AND circuit with 8 inputs, a circuit which implements the expression a∧b∧c∧d∧e∧f∧g∧h.

Condition: Use only NOR-Gates with two inputs to solve this task.

Could anyone give me a hint, what is false here? ( I would like to solve it by my own.)

My suggestion:

[image]

---

Edit:

My idea was at first to think how  can I depict an AND gate with NOR Gates.

Equation: A*B

= (A'+B')'

=>  nevertheless A'+B' is A'*B' (using here the Morgans Law) and then adding the inverter to it, it would be (A'B')'. Here the inverters are complements and would cancel each other out, so A * B would be just there

And with this equation I could work with to implement an AND gate, right?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyCnIM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: how should this work? your first input stage already only combines inputs with NORs, which aren't XORs, so you obviously lose information right there.

Comment: What do you mean with XORs? I'm not allowed to use them.

Comment: your `^` is called `XOR`, no? So that's what you need to implement. The idea would be simple: build a **two-input** XOR with NOR gates first. Build your 8-input XOR from that element.

Comment: No, ^ means AND

Comment: I should use this notation in the task as an AND.

Comment: aaaah, OK, you mean \$\wedge\$ as in math, not `^` as in the C and derived programming language!

Comment: yeah, but you've got multiple outputs driving the same net (your group of four outputs). That is *a very, very, very bad idea*.

Comment: Right. ∧ = the logic and

Comment: sorry for that confusion. Still, you can't drive the same cable with multiple outputs. What if some are high and others are low? what's the state of it then?

Comment: why do you have groups of two NORs that have the same inputs and drive the same output? That makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: hey Bud, use de Morgan's Law to solve. Don't guess.. it's wrong

Comment: What would you recommend then? i just inverted NOR gates to AND gates.

Comment: I used the Morgan's Law to express an AND gate by using NOR gates.

Comment: You will get nowhere using trial and error.

Comment: This question is qualitatively identical to the one you asked a few days ago, and it doesn't look like you learned anything from the answers to that question.

Comment: view a nor gate as "any high in gives a low out", and work with that

Comment: (look at my edited question above)

Comment: On your edit.  You cannot connect the two outputs together.  Are you trying to learn this via trial and error?

Comment: Sorry, that shouldn't happen. The Outputs of the two NOR-Gates should go separately into the universal NOR-Gate. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it that you feel lost in this. But you should be able to do this when almost asleep! Here are some easily verified equivalents. Please check them out and make sure you follow why:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwXuQb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Memorize them, if you need to. They will help you. (There are algebraic ways of saying the same thing, but these graphic equivalents are easier for some to remember.)

All you need to do is to create a 2-input AND gate out of NOR gates. From the above, it's almost trivial to see how to form a 2-input AND gate from NOR gates. And with that, the following is trivially produced:

Now that you know the above, you can work out exactly how to form a 2-input AND gate only from 2-input NOR gates. Assuming you know how to form an 8-input AND gate from 2-input AND gates, the rest should be easy.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvtg8q.png)</sup>

It's just stamping out the obvious! Really! It's that easy.

Sometimes, once you lay things out like that you may find "optimizations" you can also perform. But that's for another day.

Comment: (look at my edit in the question)

Comment: @lightsodium The equation is \$A\cdot B = \overline{\overline{A}+\overline{B}}\$.

Comment: yes, the second part of the equation was in the next row

Comment: @lightsodium Did you need any further response? Or did I cover what's needed, already?

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now.